# SQL - 'partial' group by, different behavior for different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I query my DB to extract some information from different tables. I have managed to get an acceptable result which I could probably use outside SQL. The result I got is very inefficient and I am wondering whether there is a way to get SQL do some of the work. Basically, I need to group the data more efficiently and discard some of it.

My current query results in a table which can be simplified as follows:

```
product_id | person_id | person_type | person_address | other_column
         1 |      1001 |           1 |    999 Main St | info about product 1
         1 |      1245 |           0 |                | info about product 1
         1 |      5133 |           2 |     101 Sql St | info about product 1
         1 |      9191 |           0 |    1 Query Ave | info about product 1
         2 |      5451 |           1 |    40 Table Rd | info about product 2
         2 |      6610 |           0 |                | info about product 2
```

I would like to `GROUP BY product_id`, but keeping separate `person_id` and `person_address` if `person_type=0`. Then concatenate the addresses of all `person_id` that share the same `product_id`. Keep just one value from `other_column`.
If applied to the above table, it should look like this:

```
product_id | person_id | person_address |                        other_address | other_column
         1 |      1245 |                | 999 Main St; 101 Sql St; 1 Query Ave | info about product 1
         1 |      9191 |    1 Query Ave |              999 Main St; 101 Sql St | info about product 1
         2 |      6610 |                |                          40 Table Rd | info about product 2
```

--

Alternatively, a second-best solution would be the following:
`GROUP BY product_id`, keep the `person_id` that have `person_type=0` and concatenate them if more than one share the same `product_id`, concatenate `person_address`, and keep just one `other_column`. The result should look like this table:

```
product_id |  person_id |                       person_address | other_column
         1 | 1245; 9191 | 999 Main St; 101 Sql St; 1 Query Ave | info about product 1
         2 |       6610 |                          40 Table Rd | info about product 2
```

--

To give some background, I have 2 objectives: the first is to extract `other_column` but discard the unnecessary duplicates. It is textual information so quite heavy.
The second objective is to be able to obtain *some* location information for those `person_id` that do not have a `person_address`.

(I tried searching for similar questions, didn't find anything.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    t1.product_id, t1.person_id,
    t1.person_address,
    group_concat(t2.person_address) as other_address
from Table1 as t1
    left outer join Table1 as t2 on
        t2.product_id = t1.product_id and t2.person_id <> t1.person_id
where t1.person_type = 0
group by t1.product_id, t1.person_id
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57d64/4)</kbd>**